# How does one run allure plugin in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, allure

I'm building pipeline/jenkins-based CI for several projects and want to store allure results just as it would be done in regular build with fast access icon. Is it possible from pipeline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We were failed to use Allure Jenkins Plugin in pipeline. It seems that it supports job-dsl-plugin only. So... just add stage where you generate report using Allure CLI and publish report as regular HTML report. Icon for it will be available on job and build screen.

**UPDATE**

Allure v2 has supported pipeline - see [documentation](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_pipeline_plugin).

```
stage('reports') {
    steps {
    script {
            allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
            ])
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did same thing, yep. [It is planned to add pipeline support in v2.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/pull/62), btw (NB: plugin name will be changed)

Comment: @Etki thanks, good news. It would be very useful in case of pipeline and parallel jobs running in docker.

Comment: Yes, they do have pipeline support in allure 2.x, called from pipeline like         allure([
                jdk: '',
                properties: [],
                results: [[path: '/allure-results']]
        ]) . Note that you should prepare them through gradle/maven tasks during build.

Answer (score 5):

install the allure plugin for your jenkins.
Go to your pipleline build configuration. click on pipeline syntax, select allure reports, fill-in the required fields, click generate syntax, it will give you the required code to be added to your existing groovy scripts

Comment: Please use capital letters and add some formatting for easier reading.

Comment: Please note for this you need to make sure you've got the HTMLPublisher plugin installed

Answer (score 4):

I am now using Allure report with Jenkins pipeline
You have to perform some additional configuration steps:

_1. Jenkins master must start with the following options as described in http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Jenkins+Plugin
(sample docker-compose.yaml)

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      jenkins.master:
      image: jenkins

      # ...

      environment:
        JAVA_OPTS: "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';\" -Djenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';\""
```

_2. HTML Publisher plugin installed from jenkins plugin center

_3. Allure report is generated by maven, sample pom.xml is here https://github.com/ludenus/mobile_test_poc/blob/master/pom.xml

```
$ mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true site
```

_4. Allure report is published by HTML publisher

```
    stage('Publish') {
        echo 'Publish Allure report'
        publishHTML(
                target: [
                        allowMissing         : false,
                        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                        keepAll              : true,
                        reportDir            : 'target/site/allure-maven-plugin',
                        reportFiles          : 'index.html',
                        reportName           : "Allure Report"
                ]
        )
    }
```